# How to use array_diff to get the missing item

Tags: php, arrays, array-difference

I'm having trouble using array_diff correctly. 
I've got 2 arrays:

```
$arr_1 = array(
        0 => array('name' => 'Day Rate 2', 'from' => 1200, 'to' => 1400),
        1 => array('name' => 'Day Rate 2', 'from' => 2000, 'to' => 2000),
    );

$arr_2 = array(
        0 => array('name' => 'Day Rate 2', 'from' => 0, 'to' => 1000),
        1 => array('name' => 'Day Rate 2', 'from' => 1200, 'to' => 1400),
        2 => array('name' => 'Day Rate 3', 'from' => 2000, 'to' => 4000),
    );
```

I want to get the values in **$arr_2** that are not present in **$arr_1**. I want it to return this:

```
0 => array('name' => 'Day Rate 2', 'from' => 0, 'to' => 1000)
```

To compare them, I first serialized the values of each item and created these two serialized arrays, which I can use to compare, using *array_diff*.

```
foreach ($arr_1 as $key => $val) {
    $arr_1_simple[$key] = serialize(array($val['from'], $val['to']));
}

foreach ($arr_2 as $key => $val) {
    $arr_2_simple[$key] = serialize(array($val['from'], $val['to']));
}

Array
(
    [0] => a:2:{i:0;i:1200;i:1;i:1400;}
    [1] => a:2:{i:0;i:2000;i:1;i:2000;}
)
Array
(
    [0] => a:2:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:1000;}
    [1] => a:2:{i:0;i:1200;i:1;i:1400;}
    [2] => a:2:{i:0;i:2000;i:1;i:4000;}
)
```

Since `a:2:{i:0;i:1200;i:1;i:1400;}` and `a:2:{i:0;i:2000;i:1;i:4000;}` are found in both $arr_1 and $arr_2,the odd one out is `a:2:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:1000;}`, which is what I thought array_diff would return.

However, the result that I'm getting is:

```
print_r(array_diff($arr_2_simple, $arr_1_simple));

Array
(
    [0] => a:2:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:1000;}
    [2] => a:2:{i:0;i:2000;i:1;i:4000;}
)
```

Can anyone tell me why `a:2:{i:0;i:2000;i:1;i:4000;}` is getting returned? I want all the items in $arr_2 that are not in $arr_1. How do I get this?

Comment: use `print_r(array_diff($arr_1_simple, $arr_2_simple));` instead!

Comment: You are getting all the items in $arr_2 that are not in $arr_1. Both the record 0 and the record 2 are not in array 1.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't noticed that until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value in array 1

```
[1] => a:2:{i:0;i:2000;i:1;i:2000;}
```

does not match the value in array 2

```
[2] => a:2:{i:0;i:2000;i:1;i:4000;}
```

Comment: Ah that's what I just saw as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`array_diff($arr1, $arr2)`. [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)  `$arr1` is array to compare from and `$arr2` is array to compare against. The function returns an array containing all the entries from $arr1 that are not present $arr2. Example

Case: 1 `array_diff($arr1, $arr2)`

```
$arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
$arr2 = [1, 3, 4];
print_r(array_diff($arr1, $arr2)); //Output: [2]
```

Case: 2 `array_diff($arr2, $arr1)`

```
$arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
$arr2 = [1, 3, 4];
print_r(array_diff($arr2, $arr1)); //output: [4]
```